# Things to take into account when internationalizing web app to handle chinese language

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, localization, internationalization, cjk

I have a MVC3 web app with i18n in 4 latin languages... but I would like to add CHINESE in the future.

I'm working with standard resource file.

Any tips?

EDIT: Anything about reading direction?  Numbers?  Fonts?

Comment: Unfortunately, the question would require very long (broad) answer, the one that would cause some people to be angry with me. Please find [this question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/98358/2554), to some extent it contains what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with these observations:

- Chinese is a non-character-based language, meaning that a search engine (if needed) must not use only punctuation and whitespace to find words (basically, each character is a word); also, you might have mixed Latin and Chinese words
- make sure to use UTF-8 for all your HTML documents (.resx files are UTF-8 by default)
- make sure that your database collation supports Chinese - or use a separate database with an appropriate collation
- make sure you don't reverse strings or do other unusual text operations that might break with multi-byte characters
- make sure you don't call ToLower and ToUpper to check user-input text because again this might break with other alphabets (or rather scripts) - aka the Turkey Test

To test for all of the above and other possible issues, a good way is [pseudolocalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudolocalization).

Comment: Thanks for your tips...  Do you know of any tools to do the pseudolocalization on resource files?